# Java- Not able to animate square, comes out as rotating square

Tags: java, animation, user-interface, methods, awt

I am new to java and need some help! My professor wants me to create 4 methods, which ultimate goal is to output a animated rotating square like I did in this earlier code that I made:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GTest2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GraphicsPanel gp = new GraphicsPanel();
    gp.delay(1000);
    int x = gp.getWidth() / 2;
    int y = gp.getHeight() / 2;
    gp.setLocation(x, y);
    for (int n=1; n <= 150; n++)  {
        gp.clear();
        for (int angle=0; angle < 360; angle += 10) {
            for (int i=0; i < 4; i++)  {             
                gp.draw(100);
                gp.turn(90);
            }
            gp.turn(10);
        }
        gp.render();        
        gp.delay(30);       
        gp.turn(2);         
    }
}
}
```

My professor supplied us class GraphicsPanel so we could do these programs of creating shapes and animations: http://pastebin.com/Ha1pdLrc

This is what I have so far, but I seem to only have been able to create a rotating square:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class G7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GraphicsPanel gp = new GraphicsPanel();
        gp.delay(1000);         
        animateCircleOfPolygons(gp);
    }

public static void animateCircleOfPolygons(GraphicsPanel gp){ 
    for (int n = 1; n <= 150; n++)  {
        gp.clear();
        drawCircleOfPolygons(gp);
        gp.render();        
        gp.delay(30);       
        gp.turn(2);
    }
}

public static void drawCircleOfPolygons(GraphicsPanel gp){
    for (int angle = 0; angle < 360; angle += 10) {
        drawPolygon(gp, 100, 4);
        gp.turn(10);
    }
}

public static void drawPolygon(GraphicsPanel gp, int sideLength, int sideCount){
    for (int i = 0; i < sideCount; i++)  {
        gp.draw(sideLength);
        gp.turn(360.0 / sideCount);
        gp.delay(30);
    }
}
}
```

I have looked everywhere for an answer to no avail, can anybody please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: "ultimate goal is to output a animated rotating square" -> "I seem to only have been able to create a rotating square". This sounds like it is doing what you want, no... ?

Comment: not quite, i can make a square rotate multiple times, but what i really want is an animation, and by that what i mean is the illusion that the shape is rolling. if you test the first set of code you'll know what i mean.

Comment: graphicspanel is in the pastebin i provided above, also thnx for helping! http://pastebin.com/Ha1pdLrc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure if I understand your issue fully, but if it is that the second example code `G7` doesn't appear to be animated (like the first) as it turns slower than in the first example code `GTest2` it's because you have duplicated the delay: `gp.delay(30);` in the second code; it appears both in the `animateCircleOfPolygons`function as well as in the `drawPolygon`function. It you remove either the code will produce identical output (as it should - it's the same logic after all).

Comment: i have tried that before and just again now and still does not animate like class GTest2, thnx for the solution thou

Comment: @useruser When I run the two version side by side they appear identical - what is the difference you spot?

Comment: the GTest2 looks like an animation, the G7 looks like the shape is just rotating an certain angle and placing a new shape in that location, if that helps

Comment: @useruser Which delay did you remove? It has to be the one in `drawPolygon`for it to work correct, otherwise the delay will be much longer as that loop executes more times. so keep the delay in `animateCircleOfPolygons`and remove it from `drawPolygon`

Comment: ok, yay now i see what you mean, i have a shape that looks like its rotating, but not the shape that I want, im going to test something and get back to you in a minute    Edit: I change some variables and put in a for loop and now i have my shape, i think i really understand why it was not working before, thnx for the help!

Answer (score 3):

I've had a quick read through you code...

Don't...

- Don't override `setSize` of `JPanel` wihtout calling `super.setSize`, doing so will have dire consequences for how your component will work
- You MUST always call `super.paintComponent` regardless of what you are doing in the method, `paintComponent` does important work and this will result in numerous paint artifacts been left on you component and/or other paint related issues
- Avoid creating a `JFrame` within a component's constructor, this makes assumptions about the use of the component which aren't healthy.  You component should make no assumption about how it might be used.
- Beware that components already have a concept of location and size, you should avoid from maintaining your own details, this leads to confusion over what you think the state is and what the actual state is...
- Your delay methods scares me.  Swing is not thread safe and all interactions with the UI should always be made from within the context of the EDT.  You should also never block the EDT, doing so will prevent from processing, amongst other things, repaint requests

> My professor supplied us class GraphicsPanel

With all due respect, your professor has absolutely no idea what they are talking about, this is a series of rudimentary bad ideas and problems waiting to happen.

Your core problem is, Swing is a single threaded framework.  This means that your `for` loop which you `draw` and `rotate` is been executed within the context of the EDT (in fact, it's likely that the component hasn't even been put on the screen yet), which means that until you exit the method, none of the paint events generated by your code can be processed.

The `RepaintManager`, responsible for scheduling paint events is always highly optimized, meaning that it is capable of coalescing multiple repaint requests into only a few actually events

Also, remember, transformation will only affect what is painted after it, not before.  Therefore, rotation must be done before you do any painting in order for it take affect

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/), [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) and [Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) for more details

Comment: Reading what you posted above, I still have a lot to go before I really understand everything you stated. I really need to know about Java, that's why I am going get tutored over the summer by friend who is fluent with java, but thnx for pointing out the flaws of the code. :)